# Is it ethical to employ freelancers on a per-success level and turning down late submissions?

Tags: freelancing

I work on software solutions and whenever I hit a wall and stackoverflow can't help me, I post my problems to websites where freelancers are looking for gigs.

What's special in my case is, that it's not given that all the freelancers applying for the gig can actually solve the problem. Many use bots to automatically contact me whenever I post a new gig etc.

A conversation usually consists of

- the freelancer asking for more info
- me providing the info and assistance they need
- a few minutes or hours of silence
- the freelancer saying "I think I have it" or saying "sorry I can't help"

Before showing me the code, we agree on a sum to pay, I get to see the code and if it's working on my computer I will wire the money to them.

Now the thing is because "I think I have it" doesn't come as often as "sorry I can't help" I usually am in contact with more than one freelancer at a time. As soon as one has it, I tell the others I got it working by myself and thank them for their time. So far, no one has showed signs of disappointment etc. as they themselves probably didn't even think that they are going to solve the problem in first instance.

What bothers me is that a situation could arise where two freelancers got it working at the same time so I have to tell one of them that their work has just been for nothing as I don't need it anymore. Paying both of them would be the easiest solution but my floor isn't made out of gold either.

What would you do in my situation? Telling them upfront that I am in contact with more than one person due to the project's difficulty results in a way worse basis to start off the payment's negotiation and might scare off people who otherwise could've solved the problem within minutes and with ease because they think others are faster.

Comment: Have you considered just sticking to one or a few freelancers who have proven they can solve your type of problems, to significantly increase your individual success rate and reduce the need to work with multiple ones at the same time?

Comment: @Dukeling That comment would be better posted as an answer.

Comment: @GOATNine Maybe, but answering doesn't really mix well with voting to close. It's also indirect and also seems rather logical, so it seems likely to not be a desirable option for some reason or another.

Answer (score 6):

> What bothers me is that a situation could arise where two freelancers
>   got it working at the same time so I have to tell one of them that
>   their work has just been for nothing as I don't need it anymore.
>   Paying both of them would be the easiest solution but my floor isn't
>   made out of gold either.
>
> What would you do in my situation?

If you feel you must string along several freelancers, then simply specify in your task description that the first acceptable solution wins. Then you only pay one and the others lose.

Those websites are a race-to-the-bottom situation. And you have seen the side-effects of that situation - freelancers trying to "win" by holding your attention until they either solve the problem or give up, bots, incomplete solutions, etc.

If you want to pay the lowest amount possible then you have to live with those sorts of situations. Just make your goals and methods of determining the winner clear up front.

Comment: First acceptable solution sounds like a 1980's programming competition.  The code that comes out of first-across-the-line development is pretty unmaintainable.  Perhaps you've added in requirements to offset that; but, if you haven't, you're setting yourself up for future costs that could ecplise your budget, killing off new feature development.

Answer (score 5):

How I do it is I put the job out and only take one freelancer. But I don't take them until they are sure they can do the job and they don't start work until I have confirmed they will be doing it and the details they'll be doing it under.

So until I confirm that rate, timeframe and payment method, I'm not employing him/her. If they don't solve my problem in the timeframe they agreed to, I don't pay them and I find someone else.

Once I find someone I like I tend to give any work that fits their skills to them.